# How can I change the shape in geom_dotplot and see all the dot is the same frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use geom_dotplot to distinguish two different variables by shape of the dots and two categories with color. For example I have this dataset:

```
Position    phaseGroup  phaseGroup_2    phaseGroup_3    Synonymous  Information Phasing Pha_Syn Grouped yPos
5.85E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   1
5.96E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   2
6.22E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   3
6.26E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   4
7.22E+04    NA  1   1   16  1.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 1   5
7.30E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   6
2.03E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   7
2.48E+05    2   2   2.1 1   1.2 Phased  Phased-1    1   8
2.53E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   9
2.53E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   10
2.54E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   11
2.54E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   12
2.54E+05    NA  2   2.2 16  1.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 1   13
2.55E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   14
2.56E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   15
2.58E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   16
2.61E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   17
5.76E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   18
5.77E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   19
5.77E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   20
5.79E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   21
6.22E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   22
6.23E+05    3   3   3.1 1   1.3 Phased  Phased-1    1   23
6.24E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   24
6.25E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   25
6.26E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   26
6.27E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   27
6.29E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   28
6.29E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   29
6.31E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   30
6.32E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   31
6.32E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   32
6.34E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   33
6.35E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   34
6.37E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   35
6.76E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   36
6.82E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   37
7.40E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   38
7.57E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   39
7.60E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   40
7.61E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   41
7.61E+05    3.5 3.5 3.5 16  2.1 Phased  Phased-16   2   41.5
2.03E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   42
2.10E+06    4   4   4   1   3.4 Phased  Phased-1    3   43
2.15E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   44
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   45
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   46
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   47
2.17E+06    4   4   4   1   3.4 Phased  Phased-1    3   48
2.18E+06    NA  4   4   1   3.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  3   49
2.36E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   50
2.36E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   51
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   52
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   53
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   54
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   55
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   56
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   57
2.50E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   58
2.50E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   59
2.53E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   60
2.54E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   61
2.54E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   62
2.56E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   63
2.60E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   64
2.62E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   65
3.04E+06    NA  5   5   1   4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  4   66
3.17E+06    NA  5   5   1   4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  4   67
3.84E+06    NA  5   5   16  4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 4   68
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   69
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   70
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   71
4.00E+06    6   6   6   1   5.6 Phased  Phased-1    5   72
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   73
4.00E+06    NA  6   6   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   74
4.00E+06    NA  6   6   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   75
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   76
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   77
4.00E+06    7   7   7   1   5.7 Phased  Phased-1    5   78
4.00E+06    7   7   7   1   5.7 Phased  Phased-1    5   79
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   80
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   81
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   82
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   83
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   84
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   85
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   86
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   87
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   88
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   89
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   90
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   91
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   92
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   93
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   94
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   95
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   96
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   97
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   98
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   99
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   100
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   101
4.01E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   102
4.01E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   103
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   104
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   105
4.01E+06    NA  9   9   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   106
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   107
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   108
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   109
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   110
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   111
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   112
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   113
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   114
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   115
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   116
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   117
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   118
4.01E+06    NA  9   9   1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   119
4.02E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   120
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   121
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   122
4.02E+06    NA  10  10  1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   123
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   124
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   125
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   126
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   127
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   128
4.02E+06    NA  10  10  1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   129
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   130
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   131
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   132
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   133
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   134
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   135
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   136
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   137
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   138
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   139
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   140
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   141
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   142
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   143
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   144
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   145
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   146
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   147
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   148
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   149
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   150
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   151
4.03E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Phased  Phased-16   5   152
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   153
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   154
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   155
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   156
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   157
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   158
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   159
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   160
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   161
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   162
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   163
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   164
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   165
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   166
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   167
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   168
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   169
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   170
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   171
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   172
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   173
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   174
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   175
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   176
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   177
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   178
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   179
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   180
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   181
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   182
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   183
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   184
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   185
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   186
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   187
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   188
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   189
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   190
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   191
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   192
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   193
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   194
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   195
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   196
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   197
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   198
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   199
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   200
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   201
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   202
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   203
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   204
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   205
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   206
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   207
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   208
4.59E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   209
```

I run the following command line:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(A, aes(x = factor(Grouped), y = phaseGroup_2, fill = factor(Phasing))) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y",stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.3) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

and generated the figure in attachment.

[image: PhasedGroups Data Based on Grouped Categories]

However, I'd like to do two things on this figure as you can see Group 5 at y=10 I can't see all the dots but if I make the dots smaller I can't see the color. Secondly, I would like to change the shapes of the figure according to the `Synonymous` column (1 - open circle and 16 - closed circle).

My question is how I can change the shape of the dots and optimized the figure in a way that I can see all the dots? Important note is that I would like to keep the same number of horizontal data meaning that as you can see in group 1 I have three horizontal data points and in group 2 only one.

Is there any way to optimize this figure and do I need to try another command line in ggplot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you [can't change the shape](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1111) in `geom_dotplot()`, although maybe you could mix in `color` and `fill` for the two different variables.  Another option might be something from [package **ggbeeswarm**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbeeswarm/vignettes/usageExamples.pdf), although that may fail to keep the data lined up in the exact way it is right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion I will have a look at it now. However I'd like to really keep the data in lined up. Let's have a try. Cheers.

Comment: Your code does _not_ reproduce the graph you were adding...

Comment: Sorry! Just corrected it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  A %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(Grouped == 4, phaseGroup_2 + 0.2, phaseGroup_2))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_dotplot(
    aes(x = Grouped, y = y, group = Grouped, fill = factor(Phasing))
    binaxis = "y",
    stackdir = "center",
    dotsize = 0.6
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:5), limits = c(-6, 16)) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

I noticed that you had 2 groups sitting on top of each other when `phaseGroup_2 == 4` so I bumped that group up some.

Also, please give us your dataset as code in the future. The `datapasta` package has a nice add-in to paste something on your clipboard from excel to a tribble or data.frame.
https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html

Comment: Thank you so much yake84. This is an interesting alternative and will have a look how it looks in the rest of the dataset. Datapasta package seems interesting I'll have a look at it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP is looking for a visualisation of multiple categorial data. The OP tries to use `ggplot2::geom_dotplot()` to visualise counts by 4 categories `phaseGroup_2`, `Grouped`, `Phasing`, and `Synonymous`.

This answer tries to explore different approaches:

1. Workaround for `geom_dotplot()`
2. `ggbeeswarm`
3. `vcd` and `ggmosaic`

#### Workaround for `geom_dotplot()` using `interaction()`

As already [mentioned by aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955847/how-can-i-change-the-shape-in-geom-dotplot-and-see-all-the-dot-is-the-same-frame#comment98563874_55955847), `geom_dotplot()` does not recognize the `shape` aesthetic. Using the `colour` or the `alpha` aesthetic instead does not give well discernible results for the small dot sizes the OP is requesting.

A workaround is to use the `colour` and `fill` aesthetics for a combination (interaction) of the variables `Phasing` and `Synonymous`. Both variables are dichotomous. Therefore, only 4 different colours are required.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(A) + 
  aes(x = factor(Grouped),
      y = phaseGroup_2,
      colour = interaction(Phasing, Synonymous),
      fill = interaction(Phasing, Synonymous)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y",
               stackdir = "center",
               dotsize = 0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(A$phaseGroup_2), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "RdBu", 
                      direction = -1, 
                      aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")) +
  expand_limits(x = 6) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

`geom_dotplot()` uses filled circles which plots a black outline around each dot if only the `fill` aesthetic is used. To improve perception, the same coding is used for `colour` and `fill`.

*However, not all dots are fully visible as some dots are masked behind others due to overplotting.* In particular, blue dots for the `Synonymous == 1` cases are nearly invisible.

BTW, instead of `interaction(Phasing, Synonymous)` the equivalent column `Pha_Syn` in OP's dataset could have been used directly.

Further improvements include:

- The x axis is expanded to prevent dots in `Grouped == 5` from being cut off (as requested by the OP).
- The y axis is plotted as a continuous variable so that the non-equi distances between 3, 3.5, and 4 become visible.

#### `ggbeeswarm`

`geom_beeswarm()` understands the same aesthetics as `geom_point()` including the `shape` aesthetic. Furthermore, it avoids overplotting.

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(A) + 
  aes(x = Grouped,
      y = phaseGroup_2,
      colour = Phasing,
      shape = Synonymous) +
  geom_beeswarm() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(A$Grouped), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(A$phaseGroup_2), minor_breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_shape_identity() + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Open and filled circles can be clearly distinguished.

#### `vcd` and `ggmosaic`

The `vcd` package contains a number of different plots for *Visualizing Categorical Data*. I have tried to find a good visualisations using `mosaic()`, `doubledecker()`, and `tile()` from the `vcd` package (and the corresponding `ggplot2` versions from the `ggmosaic` package) but none of them gave satisfactory results due to the large number of empty cells, unfortunately.

#### Reproducible data

The `fread()` function from the `data.table` package is able to read OP's data without additional manual intervention.

```
A <- data.table::fread("
Position    phaseGroup  phaseGroup_2    phaseGroup_3    Synonymous  Information Phasing Pha_Syn Grouped yPos
5.85E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   1
5.96E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   2
6.22E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   3
6.26E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   4
7.22E+04    NA  1   1   16  1.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 1   5
7.30E+04    1   1   1   16  1.1 Phased  Phased-16   1   6
2.03E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   7
2.48E+05    2   2   2.1 1   1.2 Phased  Phased-1    1   8
2.53E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   9
2.53E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   10
2.54E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   11
2.54E+05    2   2   2.1 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   12
2.54E+05    NA  2   2.2 16  1.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 1   13
2.55E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   14
2.56E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   15
2.58E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   16
2.61E+05    2   2   2.2 16  1.2 Phased  Phased-16   1   17
5.76E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   18
5.77E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   19
5.77E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   20
5.79E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   21
6.22E+05    3   3   3.1 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   22
6.23E+05    3   3   3.1 1   1.3 Phased  Phased-1    1   23
6.24E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   24
6.25E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   25
6.26E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   26
6.27E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   27
6.29E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   28
6.29E+05    3   3   3.2 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   29
6.31E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   30
6.32E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   31
6.32E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   32
6.34E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   33
6.35E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   34
6.37E+05    3   3   3.3 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   35
6.76E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   36
6.82E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   37
7.40E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   38
7.57E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   39
7.60E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   40
7.61E+05    3   3   3.4 16  1.3 Phased  Phased-16   1   41
7.61E+05    3.5 3.5 3.5 16  2.1 Phased  Phased-16   2   41.5
2.03E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   42
2.10E+06    4   4   4   1   3.4 Phased  Phased-1    3   43
2.15E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   44
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   45
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   46
2.16E+06    4   4   4   16  3.4 Phased  Phased-16   3   47
2.17E+06    4   4   4   1   3.4 Phased  Phased-1    3   48
2.18E+06    NA  4   4   1   3.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  3   49
2.36E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   50
2.36E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   51
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   52
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   53
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   54
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   55
2.37E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   56
2.37E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   57
2.50E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   58
2.50E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   59
2.53E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   60
2.54E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   61
2.54E+06    5   5   5   1   3.5 Phased  Phased-1    3   62
2.56E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   63
2.60E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   64
2.62E+06    5   5   5   16  3.5 Phased  Phased-16   3   65
3.04E+06    NA  5   5   1   4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  4   66
3.17E+06    NA  5   5   1   4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  4   67
3.84E+06    NA  5   5   16  4.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 4   68
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   69
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   70
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   71
4.00E+06    6   6   6   1   5.6 Phased  Phased-1    5   72
4.00E+06    6   6   6   16  5.6 Phased  Phased-16   5   73
4.00E+06    NA  6   6   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   74
4.00E+06    NA  6   6   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   75
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   76
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   77
4.00E+06    7   7   7   1   5.7 Phased  Phased-1    5   78
4.00E+06    7   7   7   1   5.7 Phased  Phased-1    5   79
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   80
4.00E+06    7   7   7   16  5.7 Phased  Phased-16   5   81
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   82
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   83
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   84
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   85
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   86
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   87
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   88
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   89
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   90
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   91
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   92
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   93
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   94
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   95
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   96
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   97
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   98
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   99
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   100
4.00E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   101
4.01E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   102
4.01E+06    8   8   8   16  5.8 Phased  Phased-16   5   103
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   104
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   105
4.01E+06    NA  9   9   16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   106
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   107
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   108
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   109
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   110
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   111
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   112
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   113
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   114
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   115
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   116
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   117
4.01E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   118
4.01E+06    NA  9   9   1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   119
4.02E+06    9   9   9   16  5.9 Phased  Phased-16   5   120
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   121
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   122
4.02E+06    NA  10  10  1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   123
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   124
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   125
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   126
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   127
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   128
4.02E+06    NA  10  10  1   5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-1  5   129
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   130
4.02E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   131
4.02E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   132
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   133
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   134
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   135
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   136
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   137
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   138
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   139
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   140
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   141
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   142
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   143
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   144
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   145
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   146
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   147
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   148
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   149
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   150
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   151
4.03E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Phased  Phased-16   5   152
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   153
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   154
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   155
4.03E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   156
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   157
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   158
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   159
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   160
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   161
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   162
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   163
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   164
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   165
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   166
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   167
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   168
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   169
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   170
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   171
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   172
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   173
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   174
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   175
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   176
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   177
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   178
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   179
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   180
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   181
4.04E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   182
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   183
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   184
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   185
4.04E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   186
4.04E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   187
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   188
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   189
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   190
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   191
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   192
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   193
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   194
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   195
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   196
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   197
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   198
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   199
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   200
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   201
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   202
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   203
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   204
4.05E+06    10  10  10  16  5.1 Phased  Phased-16   5   205
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   206
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   207
4.05E+06    10  10  10  1   5.1 Phased  Phased-1    5   208
4.59E+06    NA  10  10  16  5.NA    Unphased    Unphased-16 5   209")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Uwe. This is really helpful and I manage to generate the plot by using your command. I'll keep in mind all your suggestions and information. Thank you so much for your time.