# R: Make a box plot using different shapes for data points with no overlapping data points using geom_dotplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, boxplot, dot-plot

I have a dataset that looks like this. It's saved as a file called "prescriptivism_scores.csv":

| Usage_Guide | Usage_Problem | Prescriptivism_Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book 1 | who/whom | 2 |
| Book 2 | who/whom | 2 |
| Book 3 | who/whom | 2.5 |
| Book 4 | who/whom | 4 |
| Book 5 | who/whom | 2 |
| Book 6 | who/whom | 1.5 |
| Book 7 | who/whom | 3 |
| Book 8 | who/whom | 2 |
| Book 9 | who/whom | 4 |
| Book 10 | who/whom | 4 |
| Book 11 | who/whom | 2 |

I used this code

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv(file = 'prescriptivism_scores.csv')
ggplot(df, aes(y = Prescriptivism_Index, x = Usage_Problem)) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "#838383") +
  
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.5, color = "#00853E", fill = "#C4D600", stackratio = 1.5) +
 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Usage Problem", 
                   breaks = c("different_to_than_from", "I_for_me", "lay_lie", "less_fewer", "none", "singular_they", "split_infinitive", "who_whom"),
                   labels = c("DIFF TO/THAN/FROM", "I FOR ME", "LAY/LIE", "LESS/FEWER", "NONE", "SG THEY", "SPLIT INF", "WHO/WHOM")) +
  
  ylab("Prescriptivism Index") +
  
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom="point", shape=3, size=3, color="#EF4B81") +
 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.25, color = "darkgray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 2, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.25, color = "darkgray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.25, color = "darkgray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4, linetype = "dashed", linewidth = 0.25, color = "darkgray")
```

to create this box plot

[Box plot with no overlapping data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGOPT.png)

I'm happy with everything about this box plot except for one thing: I want each dot in the plot to be a different shape to represent the different books in the "Usage_Guide" column of my data. I want to do this so I know which data points correspond to which books.

I've tried adding "shape = Usage_Guide" to the aes() function.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Prescriptivism_Index, x = Usage_Problem, shape = Usage_Guide)) +
```

But when I do, the dots don't actually change shape, and the dotplot changes so that the dots are overlapping. It also adds dashes to the plot:

[Box plot with no box, overlapping data points, and dashes added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79qI5.png)

If I try to change the color of the dots instead of the shape, I get closer to my end goal, but strange things also happen.

For example, adding a color call to the aes() function and changing the fill to white in the geom_dotplot() function, as shown in the code below, changes the colors of the dots and maintains the box plots, but it causes the data points to overlap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Prescriptivism_Index, x = Usage_Problem, color = Usage_Guide)) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "#838383") +
  
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.5, fill = "#FFFFFF", stackratio = 1.5) +
```

[Box plot with colored overlapping data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMBpT.png)

But just reversing the fill and outline so the fill call is in the aes() function the color call is in the geom_dotplot() function breaks something so that the box plots no longer show.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Prescriptivism_Index, x = Usage_Problem, fill = Usage_Guide)) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "#838383") +
  
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.5, color = "#FFFFFF", stackratio = 1.5) +
```

[Box plot with no box and overlapping colored data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXuCX.png)

How can I maintain the look of my original box plot, but with different shapes for each data point?

Comment: Does this related question help?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55955847/how-can-i-change-the-shape-in-geom-dotplot-and-see-all-the-dot-is-the-same-frame

Comment: I see that geom_dotplot does not list `shape` as one of the aesthetics it understands. I suspect there is not a way to independently group by one variable but display dots within a group differently.

Comment: With `geom_dotplot` this seems not to be possible: <https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1111>

Comment: @JonSpring, thanks so much for sharing the link! The beeswarm package seems to be what I'm looking for. I'm still running into an issue, though, when I try to add the shape call to the aes function, it adds the shapes, but it still removes the box plot (it doesn't remove the box plot when I add a color call. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If the shapes relate to the points but not the boxplot, use `aes(shape = ...)` inside the geoms that need it, but leave that out of your global `aes()` call in the `ggplot()` line.